# Really big number

Tags: c++, biginteger

First of all apologies if there is already a topic like this but I have not found... I need to know how to handle a really big number such as the result of 789^2346:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    cout << pow(789,2346) << endl;
}
```

Comment: "court" is supposed to be "cout", right?

Comment: You should maybe clarify if your big numbers need to be floating point or integer.

Comment: You forgot to vote up & choose the best answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could try the [GNU MP Bignum Library](http://gmplib.org/) or [ttmath](http://www.ttmath.org/samples). This link point to some samples. It is very easy to use.

Comment: There is also the Big Number library in OpenSSL crypto section:  http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/bn.html

Answer (score 4):

You need a "big number" library. A popular choice is [GNU's Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library](http://gmplib.org/), which has a C interface. I's also been around for a while. Another one, for C++, is [Big Integer Library](http://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/).

I'm sure there is a list of bignum libraries on SO somewhere, but I cannot find it. There is [a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bignum) you could stroll through.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider NTL (Number Theory Library) for C++ - http://www.shoup.net/ntl/ . It's very easy to use.

If you can relax C++ requirement, Perl and Python support big integers natively. PHP supports via bcmath or gmp extensions.